# Hive select from table as complex type

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Considering a base table `employee` and a table derived from employee called `employee_salary_period` which contains a complex datatype `map`. How to select and insert data from `employee` into `employee_salary_period` where `salary_period_map` is a key value pair i.e. `salary: period`

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
  emp_id bigint,
  name string, 
  address string,
  salary double, 
  period string,
  position string
  )
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  dept_id bigint)
 STORED AS PARQUET


CREATE TABLE employee_salary_period(
  emp_id
  name string, 
  salary string, 
  period string,
  salary_period_map Map<String,String>,
  )
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  dept_id bigint)
 STORED AS PARQUET
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to select data as salary_period_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `str_to_map` function provided by hive. I hope you have only one key (salary) in you map

```
select
emp_id
name, 
salary, 
period,
str_to_map(concat(salary,":",period),'&',':')  as  salary_period_map
from employee_salary_period
```